# Tkinter error. random syntax error in weird place

Tags: python, tkinter

I keep getting this random syntax error in my code where I don't think I should get one. it just highlights a random space and I have tried changing multiple things (eg. variable names, amount of speech marks, changing speech marks to inverted commas and how many spaces in the speech marks are in from the side)

```
  if len(inventorylist) == 0:
       Label_i = Label( windowi, relief = "groove", width = 50 )
       Label_i.grid( row = 1, column = 76, rowspan = 50, columnspan = 100, padx = ( 10, 10 ) )
       Label_i.configure( text = """In your inventory you have:
       """ )

   elif len(inventorylist) == 5:
       Label_i = Label( windowi, relief = "groove", width = 50 )
       Label_i.grid( row = 1, column = 76, rowspan = 50, columnspan = 100, padx = ( 10, 10 ) )
       inv0 = str(inventorylist[0])
       inv1 = str(inventorylist[1])
       inv2 = str(inventorylist[2])
       inv3 = str(inventorylist[3])
       inv4 = str(inventorylist[4])
       Label_i.configure( text = """In your inventory you have:
       """ + inv0 + """, """ + inv1 + """, """ + inv2 + """, """ +
       """""" + inv3 + """, """ + inv4 )


   elif len(inventorylist) == 6:
       Label_i = Label( windowi, relief = "groove", width = 50 )
       Label_i.grid( row = 1, column = 76, rowspan = 50, columnspan = 100, padx = ( 10, 10 ) )
       inv0 = str(inventorylist[0])
       inv1 = str(inventorylist[1])
       inv2 = str(inventorylist[2])
       inv3 = str(inventorylist[3])
       inv4 = str(inventorylist[4])
       inv5 = str(inventorylist[5])
       Label_i.configure( text = """In your inventory you have:
       """ + inv0 + """, """ + inv1 + """, """ inv2 + """, """ +
       """""" + inv3 + """, """ + inv4 + """, """ + inv5 )
```

The error i get is a syntax one and highlights *this* area:

```
elif len(inventorylist) == 6:
    Label_i = Label( windowi, relief = "groove", width = 50 )
    Label_i.grid( row = 1, column = 76, rowspan = 50, columnspan = 100, padx = ( 10, 10 ) )
    inv0 = str(inventorylist[0])
    inv1 = str(inventorylist[1])
    inv2 = str(inventorylist[2])
    inv3 = str(inventorylist[3])
    inv4 = str(inventorylist[4])
    inv5 = str(inventorylist[5])
    Label_i.configure( text = """In your inventory you have:
    """ + inv0 + """, """ + inv1 + """, """ inv2 + """, """ +
    """""" + inv3 + """, """ + inv4 + """, """ *this space here* + inv5 )
```

Comment: You're missing a `+` just before `inv2` in that expression.  Why are you using triple-quotes, anyway?  Only the first string (with its embedded newline) benefits from that at all, the various comma-space strings would be just fine with a single set of quotes around them.

Comment: Your code might benefit from [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). Ex: `Label_i.configure( text = f'In your inventory you have: {inv0}, {inv1}, {inv2}, "{inv3}", {inv4}, {inv5}')`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could make it more readable using string formatting like `text = f'In your inventory you have: {inv0}, {inv1}, {inv2}, {inv3}, {inv4}, {inv5}'` or `text = 'In your inventory you have: {), {}, {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(inv0, inv1, inv2, inv3, inv4, inv5)`

Comment: you could even use `", ".join(inventorylist)`  in `text = 'In your inventory you have: {)'.format( ", ".join(inventorylist) )` and then you don't have to check `len(inventorylist)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the problem but you could write it in different way and make it shorter, more readable and maybe then it remove your problem.

You can concatenate inventory using

```
text = ", ".join(inventorylist)
```

and put in Label

```
text = ", ".join(inventorylist)

Label_i.configure(text="In your inventory you have:\n{}".format(text))
```

and then you don't have to even use `len(inventorylist)` bacause it will works for any number of items in `inventorylist`

---

**EDIT:**

to add `\n` every 3 items you can first create lines with 3 items

```
line1 = ", ".join(inventorylist[0:3])
line2 = ", ".join(inventorylist[3:6])
line3 = ", ".join(inventorylist[6:9])
```

and later join line using `"\n"` or `",\n"`

```
text = ",\n".join([line1, line2, line3])
```

if you have only 3 items then `[3:9]` and `[6:9]` will create empty lists and then `line2`, and `line3` will have empty strings and it will add `",\n"` to empty lines but it doesn't look good - but you can use `filter(None, list)` to remove empty elements from list.

```
text = ",\n".join(filter(None, [line1, line2, line3]))
```

---

```
inventorylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

line1 = ", ".join(inventorylist[0:3])
line2 = ", ".join(inventorylist[3:6])
line3 = ", ".join(inventorylist[6:9])

text = ",\n".join(filter(None, [text1, text2, text3]))

print(text)
```

---

If you expect more items in inventory then you can use `for`-loop with `range(start, stop, step)` and `step = 3`

```
inventorylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

all_lines = []

for i in range(0, len(inventorylist), 3):
    line = ", ".join(inventorylist[i:i+3])
    all_lines.append(line)

text = ",\n".join(all_lines)

print(text)
```

This version doesn't need `filter` because `for`-loop will not create empty lines.

Comment: This really helped but I was just wondering if there was any way that it can be made so that it adds a \n after every 3 things in inventory list. Thanks.

Comment: first you can join() three items (`inventorylist[0:3]`, etc.) using only `","` to create lines and then you can join() lines using `"\n"` or `",\n"` .  I will create code.

Comment: I added new example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will really help!

Comment: This is absolutely perfect and worked perfectly as well. You deserve a medal.

Answer (score 0):

Simple error:

```py
elif len(inventorylist) == 6:
    Label_i = Label( windowi, relief = "groove", width = 50 )
    Label_i.grid( row = 1, column = 76, rowspan = 50, columnspan = 100, padx = ( 10, 10 ) )
    inv0 = str(inventorylist[0])
    inv1 = str(inventorylist[1])
    inv2 = str(inventorylist[2])
    inv3 = str(inventorylist[3])
    inv4 = str(inventorylist[4])
    inv5 = str(inventorylist[5])
    Label_i.configure( text = """In your inventory you have:
    """ + inv0 + """, """ + inv1 + """, """ +inv2 + """, """ +
    """""" + inv3 + """, """ + inv4 + """, """ *this space here* + inv5 )
```

You need `+inv2` in the second-last line.

Comment: Thanks. I realised how dumb this question is now. :-)